# How to scroll the content of edittext when you click a button?

Tags: android, button, scroll, android-edittext

How to scroll the content of edittext when you click a button?

You can see the effect in a app called Calulator of android emulator.For example,when you input 'A+B' and then click the button named '=',the content of edittext scroll from 'A+B' to the result of 'A+B'.How to do it?Who can help me?

Here,thanks in advance！
Sorry!I'm a new programmer.I don't understand your reply a bit.How can I set the coordinates?I set like output.scrollBy(90,90),but it does't turn up a scroll view.
The following is my codes:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dip">
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/input" 
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:editable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:textSize="32dip"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:maxLength="17"
            android:background="@drawable/image_et1_conf">
        </EditText>
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/output" 
            android:layout_gravity="bottom"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:ellipsize="none"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:editable="false"
            android:cursorVisible="false"
            android:textSize="32dip"
            android:text="@string/output"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:maxLength="17"
            android:background="@drawable/image_et2_conf"> 
        </EditText>
    </FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should try using

```
 editText.scrollby(scrollPixelInHorizontal,scrollPixelInVertical)
```

on onClickListener of Button

Comment: these are integer variable that you have to change in pixel value. like editText.scrollby(30,0)

Comment: editText seem to have a method called 'scrollBy',but then turn up two errors:                                                  1.scrollPixelInVertical cannot be resolved to a variable    2.scrollPixelInVertical cannot be resolved to a variable                  Why?Does it need other widgets,such as scrollview,in the file named main.xml?                                                         But thanks all the same for your help!

Comment: Sorry!I'm a new programmer.I don't understand your reply a bit.How can I set the coordinates?I set like output.scrollBy(90,90),but it does't turn up a scroll view.The following is my codes and app' screenshot: